# Create indestructible service

Tags: android, service

I create service use **startForeground**. As I understand it, it allows you to get a indestructible service. But if I delete my application from the list of running applications, the service is also deleted. Can you somehow avoid this?

Comment: "it allows you to get a indestructible service" -- no. There is no such thing as an "indestructible service" in an ordinary Android SDK app.

Comment: I made it a year ago more or less. Here is the project: https://github.com/GuilleGC/MonitorApp/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/udl/monitorizacion

mmm probably is the script LocationService.java It's a background service geting your coordinates, It work either you delete the application from the list of running applications.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to create an indestructible service. You get a higher priority with `startForeground`, but it is always possible that your service gets killed.

However, this case has nothing to with priority, as the process is killed off by the user. Start your service in a different process than the activities and it should survive.